# web development/design hands on approach books?

Tags: php, html, css

I would really like to get a list of hands-on approach books, where you mostly learn by examples and not only theory. I'm looking for CSS/PHP/SQL maybe and any other hands-on books.

For example, I wasn't very comfortable reading HTML Dog (although it's a good book) and would really much prefer books like CSS Anthology 101 Tricks, where you learn mostly by examples / questions etc.

I tried to find those kind of books but couldn't really and I think I'll benefit more from them then a pure theory book where you read 300 pages without writing code.

Answer (score 2):

The Head First series by O'Reilly is a beginner series that teach you entirely through applications / examples. *EDIT: the Head First series is definitely not like any technical book you have ever read before. First and foremost it is designed to stimulate your mind and get you thinking about what you're learning creatively (e.g. cross-word puzzles, brain teasers) which, combined with the examples/code really help you understand the concepts.*

- [Head First Labs](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfwd/)
- [Head First Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520301)

The Cookbook series by O'Reilly is another good (more intermediate) series that teaches you through different examples. The structure of the book [CSS Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005764), for example, is just "recipes" (tutorials) on how to solve certain problems or accomplish specific tasks.

Comment: Agree. I taught myself php/mysql with the Head First book

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking about books, but since you mention a hands-on thing, I'll bring up my method. I'm more of a deconstructionalist. This probably works best when you've already got a programming language or two under your belt, though you don't mention if you're in that category. Note: this requires having a web server/site available to you and some existing knowledge of probably ftp/ssh.

To do this, I like to take working project and tinker with it, and then perhaps start coding a plugin or something. PHPBB is old-ish now, and originally more done for PHP4, but the source is available. Also, Drupal and WordPress. Drupal is a great tool. Drupal is the best thing since sliced bread, imo, and has a huge community and selection of free offerings. If you really wanted to get your feet right in there, then there's also [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), which is more of "just" a framework, and it's a smaller community. A required tool will no doubt be PhpMyAdmin, so get that, as well.

What you could do is get one or more of them installed on a web server, and attach a few other existing plugins like a working blog or cart, and then get in there and see how things work by making raw code adjustments. Cake may be less threatening, though. Then, just return back to ask specific questions, an you'll be an expert in 3-6mo, depending on effort (and aptitude? :)

Answer (score 2):

For PHP/mySQL try Larry Ullman's books:

[PHP 6 and MySQL 5 for Dynamic Web Sites: Visual QuickPro Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/PHP-MySQL-Dynamic-Web-Sites/dp/032152599X/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1290223800&sr=1-2)

PHP 5 Advanced: Visual QuickPro Guide

I found the books very easy to read through, there is a small amount of theory involved, but mostly practical code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I gained a lot of contemporary web development methodology from [Practical Web 2.0 Applications with PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599063). It was fun reading through as I was enjoying creating all cool stuff by my own. As this book title Web 2.0 you'll find a good examples on making things usable with HTML/CSS.

Comment: isnt it mostly a zend framework tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

For php, I invite you to read the indispensable [PHP and MySQL Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166) book

[image]

For the CSS/HTML, I recommend the [Meyer](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/au/52)'s references (book, articles):

[CSS: The Definitive Guide, Third Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527334/)

[image]

[Meyer's website](http://meyerweb.com/)